# Bash math & files

Tags: bash, programming

I need to do some math with the lines of a file and a number using bash. As in Ruby or python you can easily do string to number or viceversa. In bash all is untyped.

I have a file contain numbers like this: 1,2,3 I can iterate over it with that return exactly 2.

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

I would like to store this result in a $variable, and the adding a fixed number ((3+1)). so e.g $total = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6. How can I store the result of unix command in a variable for further use?

```
number_of_elements = $( sed 's/[^,]//g' elements.txt | wc -c ) 
echo "elements are: $number_of_elements" #2
lines = $(( $number_of_elements + 3 + 1)) & echo "lines are: $lines " #2+3+1
cat file.txt | grep -A $lines "text " > output.txt #open file, grep the "text" and the 6 lines that come after.
```

Seems there are problems: 
- command not found for line 1 / 3
- and as a conseguence grep it doesn't work with $lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit II:**
You can **NOT** have spaces in Bash when you assign a variable. This (from your post):

```
number_of_elements = $( sed 's/[^,]//g' elements.txt | wc -c )
```

...will not work. But this will:

```
number_of_elements=$( sed 's/[^,]//g' elements.txt | wc -c )
```

Remove the spaces before and after the `=` sign. Please read @heemayl's well written (and upvoted) answer on how to use command substitution!

> I would like to store this result in a $variable, and the adding a
>   fixed number ((3+1)). so e.g $total = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6. How can I store
>   the result of unix command in a variable for further use?

Something like this:

```
myVar=2
total=$(($myVar+2+3+1))
echo $total
8
```

Here, the variable `$myVar` (containing the integer `2`) is used, and then we add the integers `2`, `3` and `1` which then are saved in a new variable `$total`.

Answer (score 2):

You need command substitution, `$()`:

```
variable=$(sed 's/[^,]//g' file.txt | wc -c)
```

Now you can get the value the variable refers by using `$variable`. Note that, it is almost always a good idea to quote the variable while expanding to avoid unexpected effect (word splitting and pathname expansion), so better use `"$variable"`.

Note that, i have removed the `cat file.txt` as `sed` takes filename(s) as argument.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I need to learn deeper unix command

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_elements = $( sed 's/[^,]//g' elements.txt | wc -c )
```

Would try and run the `number_of_elements` command with `=` and the result of split+glob applied to the output of the `wc` command as arguments. In Bourne-like shells, scalar variable assignments are with `var=value` with no space character around the `=` (the `var` also has to be literal and be a valid variable name).

Also note that that `sed` command would remove all but the `,`, newline and bytes not forming part of valid characters in `elements.txt`.

If you want to count the `,` characters only, you'd do:

```
count=$(tr -cd , < elements.txt | wc -c)
```

For `,` and newline:

```
count=$(tr -cd ',\n' < elements.txt | wc -c)
```

(though beware that with some `wc` implementation, `$count` may have some leading or trailing blanks).

To add some number:

```
count=$(($(tr -cd , < elements.txt | wc -c) + 1))
```

The content of `$((...))` is treated as if inside `"..."`: parameter expansion, arithmetic expansion and command substitution are still performed. To strip the extra blanks mentioned above, you can actually do:

```
count=$(($(... | wc -c)))
```

instead of:

```
count=$(... | wc -c)
```